# Как создать RSS андроид-приложение?

Tags: rss

Как создать андроид-приложение, которое парсит с сайта новости с помощью RSS?

Comment: https://androidresearch.wordpress.com/2013/06/01/creating-a-simple-rss-application-in-android-v2/